# Visual Studio Code & Cold Fusion Markup (formatting)

Tags: coldfusion, visual-studio-code, cfml

For VSCode users unaware, Cold Fusion Markup is similar to HTML, XML, etc

```
<cfif variable is "value">
  stuff
<cfelse>
  other stuff
</cfif>
```

---

I've been using Visual Studio code as my preferred IDE, largely because I can make it feel like Visual Studio. It feels like a good hybrid between Brackets and Visual Studio.

Anyway.. there are two Extensions for CFML, and I've tried them both. They both seem functionally identical but neither one handles syntax formatting (both handle tag completion and syntax-coloring).

```
    "*.cfm": "lang-cfml"
```

and

```
    "*.cfm": "cfmhtml"
```

Being a tag-based language, I could leave it on default but the default formatter does not handle SQL well at all.

I can get by without auto-formatting but it sure is a nice feature. I tried this with the default formatter and the SQL is still reformatted to a fashion as shown below, and I lose tag completion.

```
"html.format.unformatted": "cfquery, a, [...] textarea, tt, var" (in settings.json.

<cfquery...>
    select field from table where username =
    <cfqueryparam ...value="#form.username#" /> and password =
    <cfqueryparam ...value="#encryptedpassword#" />
</cfquery>
```

which is quite frustrating to read.

Is there anything I can do besides learning to alter the extensions and seeing if I can improve it?

Comment: Mine seems to be formatting sql and cftags just fine, cfscript too. I'm using  the `ilich8086.coldfusion` extension.

Comment: @KevinB with .cfm files? Do you have .cfm configured in settings.json?

Comment: yes, with .cfm files. i didn't have to change any configs, it just worked.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the effort but by the end of trying, I removed both addons (I just had one disabled) and reinstalled that one, cleared out my settings file except for the format on save bit. I went back over the .cfm file, which is correctly colored, but will not auto format on save, on command, or even properly place the right amount of indent based on say a `CFIF` (next line should be intended one level deeper of course).

Comment: @KevinB **I won't ping you again, sorry but** Are you using any prettifier extensions like **JS-CSS-HTML Formatter**? That's the only one I've tried and it specifically says it doesn't support this file type when I try to use it.

Comment: I only have the one mentioned above, and eslint. everything else is default.

Comment: But, i wonder if maybe i'm just not understanding what you see as missing. You mentioned auto format, i... probably don't have that either and just don't expect to have it. I don't even get that with javascript files, or anything. never really needed/wanted it. The most i get is autocomplete when working with TS files.

Comment: Kevin, following up on your last comment and your first, when you say that the ilich8086.coldfusion extenions "formats" CFML and SQL "just fine", were you referring specifically to the action in VSCode to "format" code? On Windows, it's alt-shift-f, or can be reached via the command palette. This extension does not support that. Nor does the one from KamasamaK. For the sake of readers, folks have referred elsewhere  here on SO to other formatter extensions that supprt CFML, like Unibeautify, whose CFML support is based on Pretty Diff.